# Normal vector in curvilinear coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-curves

Is it true that the normal vector, or, $\ddot{\mathbf r}$ always vanishes for:

- a helix in cylindrical coordinates
- a loxodrome in spherical coordinates
- a torus knot in toroidal coordinates

When does $\ddot{\mathbf r}$ vanish for a curve in curvilinear coordinates?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $\ddot{\vec{r}}$ vanishes in one coordinate system then it will vanish in all coordinate systems. This is a fundamental property of vectors.

Comment: then if in one coordinate system $\ddot{\mathbf r}$ is nonzero, it will be nonzero in all. But  $\ddot{\mathbf r}$ is related to the curvature of the curve through  $|\ddot{\mathbf r}|$. Wouldn't the curvature depend on the manifold in which it is observed? Say, the helix has no curvature in cylindrical coordinates, but is curved in Cartesian.

Comment: Changing coordinates doesn't change the manifold. Coordinates are just different charts describing the same manifold. Have you calculated the helix to have no curvature in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Wonderful! I just calculated the curvature in both Cartesian and cylindrical coords and it is the same. What tripped my thinking is the misunderstanding that curvilinear coordinates meant looking at things in a curved space.

Comment: @Jay, fantastic! Glad I was able to help.